# Adding a framework to Watch OS 2 framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, ios9, xcode7, watchos-2

I get "Undefined symbols for architecture" error for frameworks I add to the watch os 2 framework bundle in Xcode 7 beta 5. Anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: Which frameworks are you trying to add?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run your watch app on a real device or simulator? If it's a real device It seems I have some bad news for you according to this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11714

I've struggled a lot with embedded Watch frameworks on beta 4/5 and ended up with no luck. I had to move all files from a framework directly to a Watch extension. So for now I'm waiting for the fix in beta 6.